# Print the date range on the report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a date range for a report from a selector. How can I print that range on the report header? I am inside a Crystal Report - not from code. I have a select expert using a IsBetween on a date field. The form prints everything fine. I just want to display the date range. I have tried the OnFirstRecord and OnLastRecord and WhilePrintingRecord to populate a string within a function - it just shows up as blank in the report.

Comment: where you are getting the date range from? Make your question more detail.

Comment: Select Expert - isBetween on a date field.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the NthSmallest and NthLargest functions - works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

```
// {@range}
// note case of format string
ToText(Minimum({?date_range}),"MM/dd/yyyy") + " - " + ToText(Maximum({?date_range}),"MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you for this.  I'm not sure what the OP was doing accepting his own answer that had nothing to do with the "question asked" but this has helped me (being a Crystal newbie).  +1 (and should be the accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

Add one or two Parameter in crystal report as per your requirement and then assign your date range to that parameters.

```
ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
// ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField.Name = "@Date1";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

paramField = new ParameterField(); // <-- This line is added
paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();  // <-- This line is added
paramField.Name = "@Date2";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);

CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
```

Comment: Then, drag the parameter fields to the report header (sorry if that wasn't obvious)